# How to Refer to Instance Variables that are Objects, in Python?

Tags: python

Usually, to refer to an instance variable, the variable name must be preceded with `self`, as in,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def print_x(self):
        print(self.x)
```

However, I noticed that if the instance variable is an object, this is not neccesary. That is, I can do,

```
class B:
    pass


class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B):
        pass

    def print_b(self):
        print(b)


b = B()
a = A(b)
a.print_b()
```

and calling `print_b` from an `A` object will print the memory address of the `B` object, without raising an error.

Is this equivalent to explicitly declaring `b` to be an instance variabe, via `self.b = b` in `__init__` and referring to `b` as `self.b` thereafter? And if so, is this proper convention?

Comment: This is only working by luck. The `b` that `print_b` is referencing is the `b` at global scope. Try changing `b = B()` to `b_instance = B()` and `a = A(b)` to `a = A(b_instance)`, and you will see that `print_b` is not so smart after all. Regardless of whether the value passed to `__init__` is an int or an object instance, you will still have to save it in an attribute of A, and reference it as `self.whatever` as in your int example.

Comment: @PaulMcG Ah, I remember learning that python will look outwards if it cannot find the variable it's looking for. Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: **everything** is an object. All instance variables are always objects in Python. Also, you *never use* an instance variable in your second example, you simply pass an instance to the constructor then immediately discard it in `__init__`, and refer to the global name `b` in your method. This is generally a bad practice (the entire point of a class being to avoid global state)

Answer (score 0):

> And if so, is this proper convention?

In both situations, the design **may** suffer of [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). The general rule of thumb is to always depend on abstractions, not on concretions. 
Only if  you share with us the actual code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and provide some context then we could provide a practical and better solution to your problem.